# Dynamic load component on route navigate angular 1.5 & UI route 1

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I am trying to load a component on route navigation . The reason is the html page of component is more than 1 mb . If i load on load it slows down UI , I only want to load that component once user click on particular route

Any Example will help . You can check below code i am trying . Let me know the fix .

*aboutus-component.js*

```
import AboutUsCtrl from './aboutus-controller'
export const AboutUsComponent = {
    controllerAs : 'vm',
    controller:AboutUsCtrl,
    templateUrl: './aboutus.html'
}
```

*aboutus-module.js*

```
import angular from 'angular'
import {AboutUsComponent} from './aboutus-component.js'
(function(){
  angular.module('analyzerApp')
  .component('aboutus',AboutUsComponent)
  .name
})();
```

Now on click on aboutus tab

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: 'aboutus' */'../app/aboutus-main.js').then(() => {

            setTimeout(()=>{
              $state.go('aboutus', { reload: false });
            },2000)

            //window.location.href="#/aboutus"

        })
```

aboutus-main.js

```
importModules(
  require.context('./', true, /^(.*(aboutus)\.js)((?!.*\.(js\.*))$)/i)
);

/**
 * Dynamically imports modules
 * @param request
 */
function importModules(request){
  request.keys().forEach(request);
}
```

Getting this error

```
angular-ui-router.js:3251 Uncaught Error: Could not resolve 'aboutus' from state 'home'
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3251)
    at Object.$state.transitionTo (ct-ui-router-extras.js:201)
    at Object.$state.transitionTo (ct-ui-router-extras.js:1599)
    at Object.$state.transitionTo (ct-ui-router-extras.js:1084)
    at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3179)
    at ni-footer.js:38
```

Comment: Any code example?

Comment: Not sure if it's apart of your problem but I would not use setTimout. You should use the built in $timeout service for that otherwise angularjs won't understand and re-render things properly.

Comment: Thanks for replying I changed setTimeOut to $timeout , but it didn't worked

Comment: do you have any  idea if i want to load html page dynamically . I don't want to use ng-include .